# PostgreSQL activerecord weirdness for .maximum

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord `before_save` method throwing an odd error:

```
class MyThing < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :dostuff

  def dostuff
    p self.class.maximum(:mycolumn)
  end
end
```

When I was using SQLite this worked perfectly, now—with postgresql—I get the error:

```
PGError: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block : SHOW max_identifier_length
```

The `.maximum` method works outside that `dostuff` method, so I guess I'm just asking too much at once? Is there another way to get the maximum value of an integer column that will work inside a `before_save`?

Comment: It looks like the problem was actually because I had some PostgreSQL unfriendly terms in my migration which meant the table needed actually wasn't present. Very odd error message considering that tho…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errormessage is about the max_identifier_length, the maximum length of an objectname (table, column, etc.). It has nothing to do with the SQL-function MAX(). Looks like you're using an invalid name, a name greater than 63 characters.